# getting error "variable-sized object may not be initialized"

Tags: c, arrays

When the following program is compiled, I am getting the following error:

```
error: variable-sized object may not be initialized
```

What is causing this error?

```
int loctionofmine[numofmines][2] = {0};
 int numofmines = 3;
    printf("Welcome to minesweeper!\n");
    printf("How many mines? ");
    scanf("%d",&numofmines);
    int i = 0; 
    int loctionofmine[numofmines][2] = {0};   // error is from this statement.
    while(i < numofmines){
        int j = 0;
        while(j < 2){
            scanf("%d",&loctionofmine[i][j]);
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: Did you attempt to fire up your favourite search engine and paste in the exact error?

Answer (score 0):

initialization of an array is done by the compiler at compile time yet you are trying to do it at run time. Since the value of `numofmines` is read in at run time so the value is unknown to the compiler at compile time, the compiler issues an error.

Comment: It is not correct that initialization of an array is done by the compiler at compile time. Objects of automatic storage duration generally **cannot** be initialized at compile time because they are created while the program is running, and the number of instances of a particular object (due to recursive calls to a function) generally cannot be predicted. And, while some things can be initialized by the compiler at compile time, others cannot or are not. E.g., the address of a static object may be used as an initializer but cannot be resolved until link time.

Comment: The actual reason the compiler complains about initialization of a variable-size object is this rule in C 2018 6.7.9 3 (or equivalent in whatever specification the compiler is using): “The type of the entity to be initialized shall be an array of unknown size or a complete object type that is not a variable length array type.”